# Java Lang Number Format Exception issue

Tags: java, io

I am trying to store text from a text file as a variable in a Java program.

The source code is as follows:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Write a description of class Reader here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class Reader
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private int areaNumber;
    private int studyPeriod;
    private int rentalCharges;
    private int CAPEX;
    private int OPEX;
    private double interestRate;

    private int[] rolloutPlanPerArea;
    private int householdsPerArea;
    private double adoptionRatePerArea;

    private String fileName = "practical6a.txt";

    public void run(){
        load(fileName);
    }

    private void load(String fileName){
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

            String currentLine = null;

            while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                areaNumber = Integer.parseInt(currentLine.trim());
                studyPeriod = Integer.parseInt(currentLine.trim());
                rentalCharges = Integer.parseInt(currentLine.trim());
                CAPEX = Integer.parseInt(currentLine.trim());
                OPEX = Integer.parseInt(currentLine.trim());
                interestRate = Integer.parseInt(currentLine.trim());
            }

            reader.close();

            System.out.print(areaNumber);

        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
    }
```

Each time the code runs I get a NumberFormatError for String "" as if there is nothing in the line the program is trying to read.

The text file contains values on separate lines. EG

```
7
3
2
1
```

As there is something on each line I question why the variables are not being set?

Comment: Which line are you getting the Error? Could you provide the stack trace?

Comment: you should print what you get each line. That will better assist you in debugging `System.out.println(currentLine)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> NumberFormatError for String `""`

Your **file must have ended with new empty line**. Either remove that or check for `!currentLine.trim().equals("")` before Integer.parseInt invocation.

Comment: I am able to run it fine with the numbers provided.  When I added an extra line at the end, or when I deleted all the lines and hit enter (so a line with an LF at the end), I got the NumberFormatException.  So I think rajuGT is correct.

Comment: So essentially if there is an empty line you need to check for it?

Comment: @Jane Yes. `readLine` will return empty string in that case, not `null`.

Answer (score 0):

check if String is empty

```
 if(!currentLine.trim().isEmpty(){
     myInt = Integer.parseInt(currentLine.trim());
 }else{
     myInt = 0;
 }
```